# The object that I created of the class for para constructer is showing a error. The error that I am getting is that that the symbol cant be found

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
public class StudentMain{
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter Student's Id:");
int Id=scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter Student's Name:");
String Name=scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter the Student's address");
String Address=scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("Whether the student is from NIT(Yes/No):");
String option=scan.nextLine();

if(option.equals("YES")){
    
    Student stu = new Student(Id,Name,Address);
}
else if (option.equals("NO")){
    System.out.println("Enter the college name:");
    String collName=scan.nextLine();
    
    Student stu= new Student(Id,Name,Address,collName);
}

System.out.println("Student id:" + stu.getStudentId());

System.out.println("Student name:" + stu.getStudentName());
System.out.println("Address:"+ stu.getStudentAddress );
System.out.println("College Name:" +stu.collegeName);
```

This is where the error is coming in doing stu.getStudentName(), stu.getStudentAddress(), stu.getStudentId() and stu.CollegeName()

```
}
class Student {
private int studentId;
private String studentName;
private String studentAddress;
private String collegeName;

public Student(int Id,String Name,String Address)
{
    this.studentId=Id;
    this.studentName=Name;
    this.studentAddress=Address;
    collegeName="NIT";
}
public Student(int Id,String Name,String Address,String collName)
{
    this.studentId=Id;
    this.studentName=Name;
    this.studentAddress=Address;
    this.collegeName=collName;
}
public int getStudentId()
   {
       return studentId;
   }
public String getStudentName()
   {
       return studentName;
   }
public String getStudentAddress()
   {
       return studentAddress;
   }
public String getCollegeName()
   {
       return collegeName;
   }
   }}
```

The error that I am getting is " Student stu= new Student(Id,Name,Address,collName); " non static variable this cannot be refernced from static context
and
stu.getStudentId() in the print statement is cannot find symbol
I am not able to understand why is this error occuring and how to fix it.

Comment: Declaring your `Student stu` variable before the if/else blocks will fix the "cannot find symbol" error. Blocks have their own scopes, variables declared inside won't be accessible from the outside (hence why the "stu" symbol is not found)

Comment: Concerning "non static variable this cannot be refernced from static context" I don't see anything in the posted code that would explain it, but it means you've tried to use `this` in a static method such as `main` where `this` has no meaning

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Fixed it. I put the print statements inside the if else blocks. one more question if the answer is anything else from yes and no it should ask the question again how would i do that

Comment: You're duplicating code by putting the print in both the if and else blocks, it would have been best to declare the variable before the if/else, assign a value to it in the if/else and print its content after the if/else. Concerning your new question, you will want to use a loop whose stopping condition is whether the last value read is yes or no and whose body reads a new value from the input. Once the loops has exited your last value read is either yes or no and you can act on that value.

Comment: How will i make that loop can you please elaborate

Comment: I am very new to java. I am also not able to understand how will i do the first part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218697/discussion-between-adarsh-bahadur-and-aaron).

Comment: The first part : `Student stu; if(option.equals("YES")){ stu = ... } else { stu = ... }; System.out.println(stu.getStudentId());` works fine : the variable `stu` is declared outside of the if/else blocks so it is accessible both inside and after them, and it contains the value either the if or the else branch assigned to it.

Comment: And for the loop here's a sample : https://ideone.com/EsTLv0

Comment: first part: In doing that  I am getting an error stu is already defined in method main

Comment: Most likely because you've kept `Student stu = ...` in your if/else branches while it should be a simple `stu = ...`. `Student stu;` declares the variable, `stu = ...;` assigns a value to it, and both can be combined into `Student stu = ...;` that does both

Comment: variable stu might not been initalized... i am getting that after doing that

Comment: I didn't look close enough at your original code, it's not an if/else you've got, it's an if/else if. The compiler is complaining because there's always an implicit `else` : if your value isn't either `yes` or `no` you will be left with a variable `stu` which you have declared but have never assigned a value to, and the compiler knows you can't call methods on such a variable, so it complains when it sees `stu` being used in `stu.getStudentId()`.

Comment: When you'll have implemented your loop you'll know that the variable will either hold yes or no and you'll be able to change your if/else if into an if/else that will make this compiler error disappear. In the meantime if you want you can change `Student stu;` into `Student stu=null;` which will also make the compiler error disappear, but only because it'll instead raise a `NullPointerException` when running your code if the input is neither yes or no

Comment: If it helps here's three ideone tests : [your problem simplified](https://ideone.com/l8R5B1), [fixed by assigning null from the start](https://ideone.com/1WIPg9) or better yet [fixed by having all the branches of your if/else assign a value to the variable](https://ideone.com/aZuLBH)

Comment: Re the loop and my sample http://ideone.com/EsTLv0  : I've edited it to remove the empty `while (!sc.hasNextLine()){}` which was completely useless as `sc.nextLine()` blocks until a whole line can be read from the input.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 'stu' to be available it has to be declared in the same block where it's used, or one which encloses it.  Basically, you create and instantly destroy 'stu' here (and in the bit above).

```
if(option.equals("YES")){
    ...{
        System.out.println("Enter the college name:");
        String collName=scan.nextLine();
        
        Student stu= new Student(Id,Name,Address,collName);
    }
    
    System.out.println("Student id:" + stu.getStudentId());
```

Comment: Thank you for that. Fixed it. One more thing If the option is anything else from yes or no it should ask the question again how would i do that

Comment: "one [block] outside of it" isn't a great description even if I see where you're going with it. Maybe "one that encloses it" ?

Comment: Thank you, Aaron.  The wording was clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parenthesis () in these two lines:

```
System.out.println("Address:"+ stu.getStudentAddress );
System.out.println("College Name:" +stu.collegeName);
```

it should look like

```
System.out.println("Address:"+ stu.getStudentAddress());
System.out.println("College Name:" +stu.getCollegeName());
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a copy paste mistake. Thank you for replying.